# Are the unique test strings appended to test names in sub-flows mandatory?

Tags: origen-sdk

In this [instructional video](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/) I see strings appended to test names when the tests are defined in sub-flows.  Is this mandatory?  My team understands the reason for this feature but still not loved.  Perhaps have an option to just enforce strict auditing and not create the sub-flow if there is collision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of these strings is to guarantee that there are no naming collisions when an Origen-generated flow module is inserted into a top-level test program flow alongside other tests which may or may not have originated from Origen.

If you want to turn that feature off though, then you should be able to, and this API should work:

```rb
Flow.create unique_ids: false do

end
```

However, it seems that there is a bug and this does nothing, I have opened an issue for this here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/issues/49

In the course of fixing that, I think we should add more features to the API, this is what is proposed:

```rb
unique_ids: :signature   # Append a calculated signature (default, current behavior)

unique_ids: false    # Append no unique ID
unique_ids: nil      # Append no unique ID

unique_ids: :flow_name   # Append the current top-level flow name
unique_ids: :flowname    # Append the current top-level flow name

unique_ids: :blah    # Any other string or symbol value will be appended directly
unique_ids: "blah"   # Any other string or symbol value will be appended directly
```

In addition to providing the per-flow API control, it will be possible to set it at interface level, so it may be applied to all flows, or enabled via logic, e.g:

```rb
# lib/my_interface.rb
def startup(options = {})
  self.unique_ids = :flowname
end
```

Any `:unique_ids` attribute given to `Flow.create` will override the value set on the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I've hacked before at the application level with a method redefinition:

```rb
# Some .rb file in your application
require "#{Origen.app(:origen_testers).root}/lib/origen_testers/flow"
module OrigenTesters
  module Flow 
    def sig
      nil
    end
    alias_method :signature, :sig
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a good solution until we get an official API in place

Comment: The downside to this brute force approach though is that it will also (I think) stop the generated variable names from the flow control APIs from containing a unique signature. I think there is less of an argument to ever do that intentionally, since you will not get a error from SMT upon a naming collision (like you would from a test name), just undefined/un-intended flow behavior which could be bad.